# What is the BigInteger property in JavaFX?

Tags: java, javafx, properties, javafx-8, biginteger

How to use `BigInteger` as property in JavaFX like a `String` as property is used as `SimpleStringProperty`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no built-in BigInteger Property class in java like [SimpleStringProperty](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/property/SimpleStringProperty.html) class.

So i created a **SimpleBigIntegerProperty** for you, which can be used as same as those built-in properties classes.

```
import java.math.BigInteger;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleObjectProperty;
/**
 * 
 * This class provides a full implementation of a {@link Property} wrapping an
 * arbitrary {@code BigInteger}.
 */
public class SimpleBigIntegerProperty extends SimpleObjectProperty<BigInteger>{

    private static final Object DEFAULT_BEAN = null;
    private static final String DEFAULT_NAME = "";

    private final Object bean;
    private final String name;
    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    public Object getBean() {
        return bean;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    /**
     * The constructor of {@code BigIntegerProperty}
     */
    public SimpleBigIntegerProperty() {
        this(DEFAULT_BEAN, DEFAULT_NAME);
    }
    /**
     * The constructor of {@code BigIntegerProperty}
     * 
     * @param initialValue
     *            the initial value of the wrapped value
     */
    public SimpleBigIntegerProperty(BigInteger initialValue) {
        this(DEFAULT_BEAN, DEFAULT_NAME, initialValue);
    }

    /**
     * The constructor of {@code BigIntegerProperty}
     * 
     * @param bean
     *            the bean of this {@code BigIntegerProperty}
     * @param name
     *            the name of this {@code BigIntegerProperty}
     */
    public SimpleBigIntegerProperty(Object bean, String name) {
        this.bean = bean;
        this.name = (name == null) ? DEFAULT_NAME : name;
    }

    /**
     * The constructor of {@code BigIntegerProperty}
     * 
     * @param bean
     *            the bean of this {@code BigIntegerProperty}
     * @param name
     *            the name of this {@code BigIntegerProperty}
     * @param initialValue
     *            the initial value of the wrapped value
     */
    public SimpleBigIntegerProperty(Object bean, String name, BigInteger initialValue) {
        super(initialValue);
        this.bean = bean;
        this.name = (name == null) ? DEFAULT_NAME : name;
    }

}
```

**Example 1 :**

A simple example,

```
SimpleBigIntegerProperty bigInteger = new SimpleBigIntegerProperty(BigInteger.valueOf(123456789));
System.out.println(bigInteger.getValue());
```

**Example 2 :**
With [ObservableList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/collections/ObservableList.html) example,

```
private final ObservableList<Person> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
        new Person("Jon Skeet", BigInteger.valueOf(123456789)),
        new Person("Michael Brown", BigInteger.valueOf(987654321))
);
```

Where The Person class (with person name and age-in-seconds properties) is,

```
public class Person {

    protected SimpleStringProperty personName;
    protected SimpleBigIntegerProperty ageInSeconds;

    public Person() {
        this.personName = null;
        this.ageInSeconds = null;
    }

    public Person(String person_name, BigInteger age_in_seconds) {
        this.personName = new SimpleStringProperty(person_name);
        this.ageInSeconds = new SimpleBigIntegerProperty(age_in_seconds);
    }

    public void setPersonName(String person_name) {
        this.personName = new SimpleStringProperty(person_name);
    }

    public void setAgeInSeconds(BigInteger age_in_seconds) {
        this.ageInSeconds = new SimpleBigIntegerProperty(age_in_seconds);
    }

    public String getPersonName() {
        return this.personName.getValue();
    }

    public BigInteger getAgeInSeconds() {
        return this.ageInSeconds.getValue();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not just use ObjectProperty and SimpleObjectProperty?

Comment: Well for primitive properties it makes sense and that's why JavaFX provides them out of the box. And there are additional method for String, so the StringProperty makes sense as well. But unless you want to provide special methods for the property, a custom property type is usually not required.

Answer (score 2):

There is no `BigIntegerProperty` in JavaFX (or any `BigInteger` property implementation), but you can use [`ObjectProperty<T>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/property/ObjectProperty.html) as `ObjectProperty<BigInteger>`:

```
ObjectProperty<BigInteger> bigIntProp = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();
```

This property stores one `BigInteger` instance and can be listened and bound.

**Example**

An `Application` where this type is used, which is bound to the text of a `TextArea`:

```
public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        BorderPane root = new BorderPane();

        ObjectProperty<BigInteger> bigIntProp = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();
        bigIntProp.addListener((obs, oldval, newval) -> System.out.println(newval));

        TextArea ta = new TextArea();

        bigIntProp.bind(Bindings.createObjectBinding(() ->
                        (!ta.getText().isEmpty()) ? new BigInteger(ta.getText()) : BigInteger.ZERO
                , ta.textProperty()));
        root.setCenter(ta);

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 275));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```